# How did they realize young Michael Douglas in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015, special-effects

[Michael Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Douglas) is around 70.
The first scene of Ant-Man take place in the mid 80s, and he is playing someone in his mid-thirties to early forties.

There were a number of close ups.

[image]

Vs.

[image]

Was this done with makeup, prosthetics, or CG?

Comment: Isn't this a question for http://movies.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @flq, all questions related to SF works are on topic.   This question would be on topic there too, but that doesn't impact whether it's appropriate here.

Answer (score 9):

According to an [interview in *Vulture*](http://www.vulture.com/2015/07/how-did-ant-man-make-young-michael-douglas.html), the effect was entirely done in CG. A company called Lola VFX did the work:

> As Claus puts it, **the company can make anyone "older, younger, thinner [or] fatter."** Lola first got into de-aging in their work for X-Men: The Last Stand, but their breakout moment came on The Curious Case of Benjamin Button, where they handled the aging and de-aging of Brad Pitt and Cate Blanchett's characters. Since then, they've had a long relationship with Marvel — Lola created skinny Chris Evans for the first Captain America film — and **they were brought on fairly early in the production process to handle the de-aging work in Ant-Man's prologue.**

The article further explains that Marvel wanted the process done entirely in CGI, no makeup or prosthetics, because it messes with the way light reflects off the face.

Comment: Is there more detail anywhere?   Do that film the scene with Michael Douglas and then overlay the face?   Is that his real hair?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - there's a little more detail [here](http://www.thegraphicslate.com/vfx-sfx/studios-vfx-sfx/lola-vfx-ant-man/2015/07), it sounds as though they filmed the real Michael Douglas and then altered the image digitally rather than creating an entire 3D model (as they did for young Schwarzenegger in *Terminator:Genisys*, see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKlbaU_uWpI)), note especially the comment "the team added shine to his skin by hiding the blood vessels in his nose". No word on the hair, though (maybe just a wig?)

Comment: I'm really impressed by the CGI work! I thought for sure that they used two different actors when I watched the movie.